# Internal and External Links in XML

Tags: xml, url, xslt

I'm on Day 3 of learning XML & XSL and I'd greatly appreciate any help here to understand what I'm doing wrong.

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="styles.xsl"?>
<document>
  <toc>
    <heading>Table of Contents</heading>
    <list>
      <item><xref href="#Foreword">Foreword</xref></item>
    </list>
  </toc>
  <content>
    <section>
      <title id="Foreword">Foreword</title>
      <para>Please see <link dest="http://foo.com/">Foo</link> for additional information.</para>
    </section>
  </content>
</document>
```

The XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="document">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Online Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="heading">
    <h1><xsl:apply-templates/></h1>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="list">
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="item">
        <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="title">
    <h2><xsl:apply-templates/></h2>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="para">
    <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="xref">
    <a>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm able to output HTML for the internal hyperlink--so far, so good. When I attempt to use an external URL in the XML document, the output is one long string of text.

How can I use an URL in the XML without blowing out the rest of the document?

For external URLs, is this XSL remotely close to being correct?

```
<xsl:template match="link">
  <a href="{@dest}"><xsl:apply-templates/></a>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just about there.  Just add this template:

```
<xsl:template match="link">
  <a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="@dest"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```

produces:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>Online Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Table of Contents</h1>

   <ul>
      <li><a href="#Foreword">Foreword</a></li>
   </ul>
   <h2>Foreword</h2>
   <p>Please see <a href="http://foo.com/">Foo</a> for additional information.
   </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just tried the template code suggestion but the output rendered as one long string of text. If I remove `<link href="…` from the XML everything is right as rain. Is there another way to express an external URL?

Comment: When I run this here: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog it works.  That's how I got the output I pasted.  What XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: Dan, the template you are suggesting is simply a more verbose version of what the OP already had. And that definitely works: http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBtg/1. Never use w3schools for anything related to XSLT. @JamesElliott Show this "long string" in the question and make sure you show _exactly_ the XML input and XSLT stylesheet you apply - and we need to know the processor you are working with.

Comment: I just realized that.  I wasn't familiar with the abbreviated synatx he was using.  And W3Schools was just the first google link I could find - thanks for the pointer to xsltransform.net

Comment: @Mathias I tried to access the xsltransform.net link but the site is giving me a 503 error.

Comment: @DanField Freshly booted my system and the code works! Not sure what happened. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JamesElliott At times, the site is down due to heavy workload, which is annoying - but when the site is up, it's the best web IDE for XSLT. I'm not sure I agree that this answer solves the problem - it is still unknown what caused the problem and by accepting an answer you are in fact saying this is the correct answer.

Comment: @MathiasMüller The answer did solve the problem. I was thrown off with an ampersand in the URL that I needed to write as `&amp;` in the XML. The example code mirrors what I'm working on, only I can't show it as it's proprietary info.

Comment: @JamesElliott An unescaped ampersand does _not_ give you a string of text as output, it throws an error saying that the input is malformed (unless that's what you meant by "string of text").

Comment: @MathiasMüller I assure you the unescaped ampersand did indeed result in the screen displaying unformatted text. No error message. Thank you again for your help.